# samba shadow copy cannot match

Tags: snapshot, samba, zfs, shadow-copy

The test machine is running Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS, I'm tring to expose zfs snapshots to samba share as shadow copies but failed.

Here is the smb.conf share block:

```
[Storage]
   comment = NAS Storage
   path = /storage/smb
   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0755
   directory mask = 0755
   vfs objects = shadow_copy2
   shadow:format = "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S"
   shadow:localtime = yes
   shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
   ;shadow:basedir = /storage/smb
```

And these are zfs snapshots:

```
root@samba-1:/var/log/samba# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME                                  USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
storage/smb@CST-2022.03.08-23.25.35    16K      -       26K  -
storage/smb@CST-2022.03.08-23.39.39    16K      -       26K  -
storage/smb@CST-2022.03.09-00.01.17  56.5K      -     66.5K  -
```

And I found these in logs:

```
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750713, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/smbd/files.c:824(file
_name_hash)
  file_name_hash: /storage/smb//storage/smb/.zfs/snapshot hash 0xb6dc192a
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750846, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_co
py2.c:1870(shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt)
  shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt: no match "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S": .
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750872,  6, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:2064(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data)
  shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data: ignoring .
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750892, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:1870(shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt)
  shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt: no match "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S": ..
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750910,  6, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:2064(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data)
  shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data: ignoring ..
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750928, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:1870(shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt)
  shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt: no match "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S": CST-2022.03.09-00.01.17
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750947,  6, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:2064(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data)
  shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data: ignoring CST-2022.03.09-00.01.17
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.750973, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:1870(shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt)
  shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt: no match "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S": CST-2022.03.08-23.39.39
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.751003,  6, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:2064(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data)
  shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data: ignoring CST-2022.03.08-23.39.39
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.751030, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:1870(shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt)
  shadow_copy2_snapshot_to_gmt: no match "CST-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S": CST-2022.03.08-23.25.35
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.751053,  6, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/modules/vfs_shadow_copy2.c:2064(shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data)
  shadow_copy2_get_shadow_copy_data: ignoring CST-2022.03.08-23.25.35
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.751112,  5, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0)] ../../source3/smbd/files.c:636(file_free)
  freed files structure 0 (4 used)
[2022/03/09 12:53:40.751137, 10, pid=3211, effective(101105, 100513), real(101105, 0), class=vfs] ../../source3/modules/vfs_default.c:1482(vfswrap_fsctl)
  FSCTL_GET_SHADOW_COPY_DATA: 0 volumes for path[.].
```

why the compare is **no match**? I generate the snapshot name using `date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 0):

My system is a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS lite 64bits and Samba Version 4.13.13-Debian and I'm having the same problems, but found a strange solution:

You have to set this

```
shadow:localtime = no
```

The following e-mail on the [Samba mailing list](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-August/217659.html) gave me a clue.